# How to send files larger than 1MB with ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to send a file larger than 1mb, there is no issue with file size if i send the request with html form action. but, if i try to send those files with ajax in php, it's showing error in $_FILES if file size total 1mb or larger.

my php.ini default setting is:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2G
php_value post_max_size 2G
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

I'm sending data with ajax here:

```
let formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('files[]', fileInput.files[i], fileInput.files[i].name);
}

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '../upload.php', true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

In upload.php i'm just doing

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES['files']);
echo "</pre>";
```

and it's showing this kind of file error if the file 1MB or larger

```
Array
{
  [name] => Array
    (
        [0] => image.jpg
    )

  [type] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

  [tmp_name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

  [error] => Array
    (
        [0] => 3
    )

  [size] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

)
```

Comment: Comment removed. I failed to _read_. Thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Increase upload_max_filesize = 1M and post_max_size = 2M

Comment: @Lewis - You can see it in the dump of the `$_FILES`-array. They get the error code `3`, which means the file was only partially uploaded.

Comment: It means exactly what it sounds like. The full file wasn't uploaded. If it was because of the size-limit, the error code would have been `1` - _"file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"_. You can find the error codes and what they mean [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: how can I solve this problem? @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

your html form

```
            <form  name="fileInfoForm" class="form-horizontal" id='fileInfoForm' 
            method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file"   id='file'   name='file' model="ctrl.fileInfo.file"
             placeholder='Choose file'   />
            </form>
```

And your ajax code is here to send more the 15 mb file to php script

```
<script>
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
        var file=$("#file").val().split("\\").pop();
        var form=document.getElementById('fileInfoForm');
        var fd=new FormData(form);
        fd.append('file',file);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',

            url: 'your_file.php',
            data: fd,
            dataType: "json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
            }


        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click event get input type file prop using id and make that form data

```
// On button click event
    $('#upload').on('click', function() {
        var file_data = $('#fileToUpload').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'server_file.php',
            dataType: 'json', 
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                         
            type: 'post',
            beforeSend: function (){
                // ...
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(response){
                var response = response.responseJSON;
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

And on server:

```
echo "<pre>";

print_r($_FILES);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is for laravel framework but the ajax request is same everywhere, I just wanted to show you that once you have include `enctype="mulitpart/form-data"` in your form tag. And then you have used the array like brackets as well. like file `name="file[]"`, then don't do anything else, i mean to say it gives you all files with array indexes. And In this case I am not facing any max file size error etc... It's just for your help.

```
$(document).on('click','#hide_btn', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(this.form);

        //$.ajaxSetup({
        //    headers: {
        //        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        //    }
        //});

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '{{ route("visa.store") }}',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,

            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },

            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My Laravel project was hosted in vagrant. I fixed it by editing the php.ini and nginx.conf files. I did the following commands.

1- vagrant ssh  -- to enter the vagrant

2- cd ../cd .. etc/php/7.4/cli       -- to find php.ini file

3- sudo vim php.ini     -- to open the php.ini file

4- Then I updated the upload_max_filesize = 20M; and saved the file by :wq command.

5- sudo service php7.4-fpm restart

6- etc/nginx       -- to find nginx.conf file

7- sudo vi nginx.conf    -- to open the nginx.conf file

8- I added server {client_max_body_size 10M;} and client_max_body_size 10M; inside http block

9- I saved the nginx.conf by :qw! and restarted the nginx server by sudo service nginx restart

I hope it help. Thanks